# How to select elements in namespace scope and get rid of empty default namespace in the output

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to transform the following input file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>http://worksite.imanage.com/SearchDocumentsResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:b9b79a0f-b4de-4686-9c54-51c5a7f99331</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:8e88f531-8369-4557-80bf-e8a9835d8eb3</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-ea526ce6-ca66-4aaf-aae9-cf2fe8d5cbad">
                <wsu:Created>2011-06-01T07:09:20Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2011-06-01T07:14:20Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <SearchDocumentsResult xmlns="http://worksite.imanage.com">
            <Documents>
                <Document>
                    <ObjectID>!nrtdms:0:!session:PTHT096:!database:Technical:!document:803226,1:</ObjectID>
                    <Database>Technical</Database>
                    <Profile>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileDocNum</AttributeID>
                            <Value>803226</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileDescription</AttributeID>
                            <Value>TC-D60-1087 - Compressor C-301C Installation Work Platform General Arrangement</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileVersion</AttributeID>
                            <Value>1</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileCustom3</AttributeID>
                            <Value>CV</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileDatabase</AttributeID>
                            <Value>Technical</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileExtension</AttributeID>
                            <Value>ACROBAT</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                    </Profile>
                </Document>
            </Documents>
        </SearchDocumentsResult>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

into the following output file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>http://worksite.imanage.com/SearchDocumentsResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:b9b79a0f-b4de-4686-9c54-51c5a7f99331</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:8e88f531-8369-4557-80bf-e8a9835d8eb3</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-ea526ce6-ca66-4aaf-aae9-cf2fe8d5cbad">
                <wsu:Created>2011-06-01T07:09:20Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2011-06-01T07:14:20Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <SearchDocumentsResult xmlns="http://worksite.imanage.com">
            <Documents>
                <Document>
                    <ObjectID>!nrtdms:0:!session:PTHT096:!database:Technical:!document:803226,1:</ObjectID>
                    <Database>Technical</Database>
                    <Profile>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileDocNum</AttributeID>
                            <Value>803226</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileDescription</AttributeID>
                            <Value>TC-D60-1087 - Compressor C-301C Installation Work Platform General Arrangement</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileVersion</AttributeID>
                            <Value>1</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileCustom3</AttributeID>
                            <Value>CV</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileDatabase</AttributeID>
                            <Value>Technical</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                        <ProfileItem>
                            <AttributeID>imProfileExtension</AttributeID>
                            <Value>pdf</Value>
                        </ProfileItem>
                    </Profile>
                </Document>
            </Documents>
        </SearchDocumentsResult>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have written the following stylesheet to do the job

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:w = "http://worksite.imanage.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="element()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attribute()|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "//w:ProfileItem[6]/child::w:Value">        
    <xsl:call-template name="changeDocumentExtension"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name = "changeDocumentExtension">

    <xsl:variable 
    name="iManageExtension"
    as = "xs:string"
    select="//w:AttributeID[. = 'imProfileExtension']/following::w:Value"
    />

    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'ACROBAT'">
        <Value>pdf</Value>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'ANSI'">
        <Value>txt</Value>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'EXCEL'">
        <Value>xsl</Value>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'EXCELX'">
        <Value>xslx</Value>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'PDF230'">
        <Value>pdf</Value>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'WORD'">
        <Value>doc</Value>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'WORDX'">
        <Value>docx</Value>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'WORDXT'">
        <Value>docx</Value>
    </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>               

</xsl:template>      

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output that I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <wsa:Action>http://worksite.imanage.com/SearchDocumentsResponse</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:b9b79a0f-b4de-4686-9c54-51c5a7f99331</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:8e88f531-8369-4557-80bf-e8a9835d8eb3</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-ea526ce6-ca66-4aaf-aae9-cf2fe8d5cbad">
        <wsu:Created>2011-06-01T07:09:20Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2011-06-01T07:14:20Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
    <SearchDocumentsResult xmlns="http://worksite.imanage.com">
        <Documents>
        <Document>
            <ObjectID>!nrtdms:0:!session:PTHT096:!database:Technical:!document:803226,1:</ObjectID>
            <Database>Technical</Database>
            <Profile>
            <ProfileItem>
                <AttributeID>imProfileDocNum</AttributeID>
                <Value>803226</Value>
            </ProfileItem>
            <ProfileItem>
                <AttributeID>imProfileDescription</AttributeID>
                <Value>TC-D60-1087 - Compressor C-301C Installation Work Platform General Arrangement</Value>
            </ProfileItem>
            <ProfileItem>
                <AttributeID>imProfileVersion</AttributeID>
                <Value>1</Value>
            </ProfileItem>
            <ProfileItem>
                <AttributeID>imProfileCustom3</AttributeID>
                <Value>CV</Value>
            </ProfileItem>
            <ProfileItem>
                <AttributeID>imProfileDatabase</AttributeID>
                <Value>Technical</Value>
            </ProfileItem>
            <ProfileItem>
                <AttributeID>imProfileExtension</AttributeID>
                <Value xmlns="">pdf</Value>
            </ProfileItem>
            </Profile>
        </Document>
        </Documents>
    </SearchDocumentsResult>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I would like to get some help with the following issues:

1. There is an unwanted xmlns="" element in the output that can't be removed using the exclude-result-prefixes attribute. I don't know how to get rid of it.
2. The stylesheet has two long XPaths. They do the job and point to the right elements but I can't help but cringe every time I look at them. If someone could offer a shorter, cleaner alternative, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Updated the stylesheet to reflect changes I made after implementing empo's hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simplify XPath**

I suggest you to include in your transform a declaration with prefix for the default namespaces. For example for

```
 <SearchDocumentsResult xmlns="http://worksite.imanage.com">
```

you can add `w` prefix in the stylesheet element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:w = "http://worksite.imanage.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
version="2.0">
```

This will make easier for you select elements in the namespace, thus making possible to avoid XPath match against `namespace-uri()` and simplifying your XPath.

About XPath, how much your selection must be absolute? For example the following worked the same for me:

```
"/soap:Envelope/soap:Body[1]/w:SearchDocumentResult/*[1]/*[1]/*[1]/*[6]/*[1]"
```

But you can also use:

```
"/soap:Envelope/soap:Body[1]/w:SearchDocumentResult//w:Value[1]"
```

---

**Remove Empty Namespace**

To get rid of the empty namespace appearing in the `Value` element, you need to fix your stylesheet so that each `Value` element is correctly located in the namespace. Example:

```
<xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'ACROBAT'">
  <xsl:element 
       name="Value" 
       namespace="http://worksite.imanage.com">
       pdf
  </xsl:element>
```

In this way the system will usually output the element without the namespace.

---

**Further Note about Simplifying XPath**

Note that **in certain situations**, where mostly you want to manage a specific namespace, you can simply do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
xpath-default-namespace="http://worksite.imanage.com"
version="2.0">
```

and work without namespace prefix.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Using your hint about the default namespace, I was able to simplify both XPaths. But I still don't know how to get rid of the xmlns="" that appears in the output.

Comment: @Sergey: give me a few minutes, I'm looking into it.

Comment: @Sergey: I've extended the answer to manage the empty output namespace. I hope you are ok now. Please provide feedback.

Comment: @Sergey: note about XPath further extended.

Comment: Even though I wasn't able to implement your suggestion directly, I was able to accomplish what I wanted using the stylesheet below. Wouldn't be able to do that without your hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet does the job:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet 
        xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   
        xmlns:w = "http://worksite.imanage.com"      
        exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
        version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="element()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attribute()|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "//w:ProfileItem[6]/child::w:Value">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://worksite.imanage.com">
            <xsl:call-template name="changeDocumentExtension"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="changeDocumentExtension">

        <xsl:variable 
            name="iManageExtension" 
            as="xs:string"
            select="//w:AttributeID[. = 'imProfileExtension']/following::w:Value"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'ACROBAT'"> pdf </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'ANSI'"> txt </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'EXCEL'"> xsl </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'EXCELX'"> xslx </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'HTML'"> htm </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'JPEG'"> jpg </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'PDF230'"> pdf </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'PPT'"> ppt </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'PPTX'"> pptx </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'WORD'"> doc </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'WORDX'"> docx </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$iManageExtension eq 'WORDXT'"> docx </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>      

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 point fo the effort. To my XSLT processor, both solutions are working. Which processor are you using?

Comment: I've changed the title to the question to match it better, as I normally do if necessary to the questions for which my answer was accepted. Feel free to restore it if you mind about.